# how to preserve color-interpretation when merging TIFFs and adding alpha band

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, colortable

We have a collection of black-and-white map tiles as `*.tif` images with accompanying `*.tfw` files, that we'd like to merge into one single large map and cut with a polygon (turning the area outside the polygon transparent).

`gdalinfo` output for them looks like this:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 702_232.tif
       702_232.tfw
Size is 4000, 4000
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (702000.000000000000000,233000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=96
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=96
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
  MINISWHITE=YES
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  702000.000,  233000.000) 
Lower Left  (  702000.000,  232000.000) 
Upper Right (  703000.000,  233000.000) 
Lower Right (  703000.000,  232000.000) 
Center      (  702500.000,  232500.000) 
Band 1 Block=4000x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=1
  Color Table (RGB with 2 entries)
    0: 255,255,255,255
    1: 0,0,0,255
```

So this seem to be 1-band TIFFs with a color palette.

To merge them, we're first building a VRT with

```bsh
gdalbuildvrt -a_srs 'EPSG:21781' merged.vrt *.tif
```

(as you can see, we also set the source SRS, which is missing in the input data)

The individual input files (the tiles) and the VRT display fine (black and white, as intended) in QGIS 2.18.

To build an actual single image file (and at the same time cut the result to the polygon area<sup>1</sup>), we then use

```bsh
gdalwarp \
    -cutline swissBOUNDARIES3D/FGDB/swissBOUNDARIES3D_1_3_LV03_LN02.gdb \
    -cl TLM_KANTONSGEBIET \
    -cwhere "NAME='St. Gallen'" \
    -dstalpha \
    \
    -co TILED=YES \
    -co COMPRESS=LZW \
    -co BIGTIFF=YES \
    \
    --config GDAL_CACHEMAX=40% \
    -multi \
    -et 0 \
    -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS \
    -wm 5000 \
    \
    merged.vrt  merged_and_cut.tif
```

The result is a 2-band TIFF (the 2nd band being alpha, required for the transparency after cutting) **without** a color palette. When displayed in QGIS, it appears in bright green instead of black and white.

If we add `-setci` to the options for `gdalwarp` we get a 2-band TIFF **with** a (sensible looking, even though much larger) color palette. But in QGIS 2.18, it also appears in bright green by default, at least until go to layer properties → style and manually set "Render type" to "Palette".

As the original files and the VRT work fine, I wondered whether we can use the  "Raw mode" documented at http://gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html to preserve the first band's color interpretation, but there's no indication on how to use with `gdalwarp`. (Replacing `merged.vrt` by `GTIFF_RAW:merged.vrt` in the the `gdalwarp` invocation results in an error about the file not being found.)

**How can I preserve the color interpretation with `gdalwarp`?** (So that it is correctly understood by QGIS and other software.)

#### Example data

For licensing reasons I think I cannot share the tiles I want to merge, but I've produced these two example tiles (with nonsensical content) that have the same properties and show the same behavior as the original tiles:

- Inputs (TIFFs and TFWs): [ownCloud directory](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/chhJuMZ3HJuPw2a) | [download as ZIP archive](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/chhJuMZ3HJuPw2a/download)
- `gdalbuildvrt -a_srs 'EPSG:21781' merged.vrt ../input/*.tif` results in [`merged.vrt`](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/nPlGrUZUqawv5lI) (2 KB) ([direct download](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/nPlGrUZUqawv5lI/download))
- `gdalwarp -dstalpha -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW merged.vrt merged.tif` results in [`merged.tif`](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/bfvkWCM1P6pbJ5E) (17.6 MB) ([direct download](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/bfvkWCM1P6pbJ5E/download))

---

<sup>1</sup> Thus why we use `gdalwarp`. If we wouldn't cut to a polygon, `gdaltranslate` instead of `gdalwarp` would suffice to materialize the VRT to a single TIFF.

Comment: `-co PHOTOMETRIC=MINISBLACK` doesn't seem to help either

Comment: nor does `-co PROFILE=GeoTIFF`

Comment: The issue seems to be `-dstalpha` and/or the additional (mask/alpha) band introduced by that.

Comment: Can you share two source images for testing?

Comment: @user30184 I've added links to synthetic examples to the question

Comment: For me it seems that the image is OK but QGIS has a bug and selects wrong rendering mode. Gdalinfo reports `Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette` and `Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha` so it seems obvious what is the correct interpretation but QGIS still opens the image as the "Multiband color" mode instead of "Paletted". I do not believe you can do anything better on the GDAL side.

Comment: The result also displays correctly in GIMP, so it might indeed be that QGIS is at fault.

Comment: Though, I noticed that the color palette has four-component colors (so presumably includes alpha) and `-dstalpha` produces a separate alpha band. Does that combination even make sense?

Comment: GDAL perhaps supports only RGBA palettes http://www.gdal.org/classGDALColorTable.html#a49b488f77a913fffbdffb5e4cb6b9226. Anyway, all entries in the palette have alpha=255 so having a separate alpha band does make sense. Your original 1-bit image shows also `Color Table (RGB with 2 entries)
  0: 255,255,255,255
  1: 0,0,0,255`

Comment: Whilst this appears to be a bug in GDAL / QGIS that is worth addressing. It strikes me that the obvious workaround in this case would be to achieve the transparent masking using a NODATA value instead of an alpha band, via the `-dstnodata` switch, or as a transparent pallette colour. Is this not an option?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is an option @AndyHarfoot, and probably the best workaround so far. I didn't consider it yet, because I was using the same commands _also_ for different (colored) input tiles that actually have 3 bands for RGB. I guess I'll just have start using different command lines depending on the type of input tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not this is a bug in QGIS, it can be worked around by handling trasparency with a NODATA value instead of by adding an alpha band. (Thanks to Andy Harfoot for the [hint](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274775/how-to-preserve-color-interpretation-when-merging-tiffs-and-adding-alpha-band/279919#comment446831_274775)!)

As `-cutline ...` can only distinguish between inside and outside the queried vector feature(s), there is no need for semi-transparency / semi-opacity. Thus, a NODATA value will suffice and no alpha band is actually needed.

Because the input data only uses 2 of the 256 possible values for each byte that represents a pixel, we can choose a NODATA value that won't interfere with the colors already used. In the case at hand, it just cannot be `0` or `1`. We are free to choose anything between `2` and `255`.

With this, the command becomes

```
gdalwarp \
    -cutline swissBOUNDARIES3D/FGDB/swissBOUNDARIES3D_1_3_LV03_LN02.gdb \
    -cl TLM_KANTONSGEBIET \
    -cwhere "NAME='St. Gallen'" \
    -dstnodata 255 \  # <------------------------ this line was changed
    \
    -co TILED=YES \
    -co COMPRESS=LZW \
    -co BIGTIFF=YES \
    \
    --config GDAL_CACHEMAX=40% \
    -multi \
    -et 0 \
    -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS \
    -wm 5000 \
    \
    merged.vrt  merged_and_cut.tif
```

#### Pros:

- With the same compression applied, the resulting file ([here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/5nskpqxsp4Zcr1J) cut to the boundary of canton Zug, 8.8 MB ([direct download](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/5nskpqxsp4Zcr1J/download))) will be half as large as with an alpha band.

#### Cons:

- I have to know in advance (or to detect somehow) whether the input tile set has RGB(A) 3- or 4-band images vs. paletted 1-band images and in the latter case determine a value that can be used as NODATA value without conflict. While this is easy to do "manually" by looking at `gdalinfo` output, I'd like to use this in an automated process that can take either type of input.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is a bug in QGIS, it can be worked around by creating a 4-band TIFF with a band for `Red`, `Green`, `Blue` and `Alpha` each.

This can be done by post-processing with `gdal_translate -expand rgba`.

#### Pros:

- If the intermediate result already is an RGBA image, the end result will also be, but also if the intermediate result is a paletted image. Thus, with this approach, the same commands can be used for either input (maybe at the cost of some additional processing time).

#### Cons:

- In the black-and-white paletted case, this will result in a file twice as large ([example](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/Ki2fShqDobyKErJ) 17.8 MB ([direct download](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/Ki2fShqDobyKErJ/download))) as with the NODATA approach (with the same compression applied — be sure to pass the respective options to `gdal_translate`, too, or it will be even larger).