# Is a TIFF with a 1-byte/px band and RGBA(?) palette and a 1-byte/px Alpha band valid?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, multi-band, transparency-opacity

I have a process (see [how to preserve color-interpretation when merging TIFFs and adding alpha band](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/274775/51574)) which produces a TIFFs ([download example image](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/bfvkWCM1P6pbJ5E/download)<sup>1</sup> 17.6 MB) with the following `gdalinfo` output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: merged.tif
Size is 28346, 47244
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["CH1903 / LV03",
    GEOGCS["CH1903",
        DATUM["CH1903",
            SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],
            TOWGS84[674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6149"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4149"]],
    PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Center"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.95240555555556],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.439583333333333],
    PARAMETER["azimuth",90],
    PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",200000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Y",EAST],
    AXIS["X",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","21781"]]
Origin = (672173.366739814984612,233935.800211683992529)
Pixel Size = (0.105835038426470,-0.105835038426470)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  672173.367,  233935.800) (  8d23'35.46"E, 47d15'13.47"N)
Lower Left  (  672173.367,  228935.730) (  8d23'32.57"E, 47d12'31.56"N)
Upper Right (  675173.367,  233935.800) (  8d25'58.14"E, 47d15'12.27"N)
Lower Right (  675173.367,  228935.730) (  8d25'55.13"E, 47d12'30.35"N)
Center      (  673673.367,  231435.765) (  8d24'45.32"E, 47d13'51.92"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA 
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 255,255,255,255
    1: 0,0,0,255
    2: 0,0,0,255
    3: 0,0,0,255
    4: 0,0,0,255
    5: 0,0,0,255
    6: 0,0,0,255
    7: 0,0,0,255
    8: 0,0,0,255
    9: 0,0,0,255
   10: 0,0,0,255
   11: 0,0,0,255
   12: 0,0,0,255
   13: 0,0,0,255
   14: 0,0,0,255
   15: 0,0,0,255
   16: 0,0,0,255
   17: 0,0,0,255
   18: 0,0,0,255
   19: 0,0,0,255
   20: 0,0,0,255
   21: 0,0,0,255
   22: 0,0,0,255
   23: 0,0,0,255
   24: 0,0,0,255
   25: 0,0,0,255
   26: 0,0,0,255
   27: 0,0,0,255
   28: 0,0,0,255
   29: 0,0,0,255
   30: 0,0,0,255
   31: 0,0,0,255
   32: 0,0,0,255
   33: 0,0,0,255
   34: 0,0,0,255
   35: 0,0,0,255
   36: 0,0,0,255
   37: 0,0,0,255
   38: 0,0,0,255
   39: 0,0,0,255
   40: 0,0,0,255
   41: 0,0,0,255
   42: 0,0,0,255
   43: 0,0,0,255
   44: 0,0,0,255
   45: 0,0,0,255
   46: 0,0,0,255
   47: 0,0,0,255
   48: 0,0,0,255
   49: 0,0,0,255
   50: 0,0,0,255
   51: 0,0,0,255
   52: 0,0,0,255
   53: 0,0,0,255
   54: 0,0,0,255
   55: 0,0,0,255
   56: 0,0,0,255
   57: 0,0,0,255
   58: 0,0,0,255
   59: 0,0,0,255
   60: 0,0,0,255
   61: 0,0,0,255
   62: 0,0,0,255
   63: 0,0,0,255
   64: 0,0,0,255
   65: 0,0,0,255
   66: 0,0,0,255
   67: 0,0,0,255
   68: 0,0,0,255
   69: 0,0,0,255
   70: 0,0,0,255
   71: 0,0,0,255
   72: 0,0,0,255
   73: 0,0,0,255
   74: 0,0,0,255
   75: 0,0,0,255
   76: 0,0,0,255
   77: 0,0,0,255
   78: 0,0,0,255
   79: 0,0,0,255
   80: 0,0,0,255
   81: 0,0,0,255
   82: 0,0,0,255
   83: 0,0,0,255
   84: 0,0,0,255
   85: 0,0,0,255
   86: 0,0,0,255
   87: 0,0,0,255
   88: 0,0,0,255
   89: 0,0,0,255
   90: 0,0,0,255
   91: 0,0,0,255
   92: 0,0,0,255
   93: 0,0,0,255
   94: 0,0,0,255
   95: 0,0,0,255
   96: 0,0,0,255
   97: 0,0,0,255
   98: 0,0,0,255
   99: 0,0,0,255
  100: 0,0,0,255
  101: 0,0,0,255
  102: 0,0,0,255
  103: 0,0,0,255
  104: 0,0,0,255
  105: 0,0,0,255
  106: 0,0,0,255
  107: 0,0,0,255
  108: 0,0,0,255
  109: 0,0,0,255
  110: 0,0,0,255
  111: 0,0,0,255
  112: 0,0,0,255
  113: 0,0,0,255
  114: 0,0,0,255
  115: 0,0,0,255
  116: 0,0,0,255
  117: 0,0,0,255
  118: 0,0,0,255
  119: 0,0,0,255
  120: 0,0,0,255
  121: 0,0,0,255
  122: 0,0,0,255
  123: 0,0,0,255
  124: 0,0,0,255
  125: 0,0,0,255
  126: 0,0,0,255
  127: 0,0,0,255
  128: 0,0,0,255
  129: 0,0,0,255
  130: 0,0,0,255
  131: 0,0,0,255
  132: 0,0,0,255
  133: 0,0,0,255
  134: 0,0,0,255
  135: 0,0,0,255
  136: 0,0,0,255
  137: 0,0,0,255
  138: 0,0,0,255
  139: 0,0,0,255
  140: 0,0,0,255
  141: 0,0,0,255
  142: 0,0,0,255
  143: 0,0,0,255
  144: 0,0,0,255
  145: 0,0,0,255
  146: 0,0,0,255
  147: 0,0,0,255
  148: 0,0,0,255
  149: 0,0,0,255
  150: 0,0,0,255
  151: 0,0,0,255
  152: 0,0,0,255
  153: 0,0,0,255
  154: 0,0,0,255
  155: 0,0,0,255
  156: 0,0,0,255
  157: 0,0,0,255
  158: 0,0,0,255
  159: 0,0,0,255
  160: 0,0,0,255
  161: 0,0,0,255
  162: 0,0,0,255
  163: 0,0,0,255
  164: 0,0,0,255
  165: 0,0,0,255
  166: 0,0,0,255
  167: 0,0,0,255
  168: 0,0,0,255
  169: 0,0,0,255
  170: 0,0,0,255
  171: 0,0,0,255
  172: 0,0,0,255
  173: 0,0,0,255
  174: 0,0,0,255
  175: 0,0,0,255
  176: 0,0,0,255
  177: 0,0,0,255
  178: 0,0,0,255
  179: 0,0,0,255
  180: 0,0,0,255
  181: 0,0,0,255
  182: 0,0,0,255
  183: 0,0,0,255
  184: 0,0,0,255
  185: 0,0,0,255
  186: 0,0,0,255
  187: 0,0,0,255
  188: 0,0,0,255
  189: 0,0,0,255
  190: 0,0,0,255
  191: 0,0,0,255
  192: 0,0,0,255
  193: 0,0,0,255
  194: 0,0,0,255
  195: 0,0,0,255
  196: 0,0,0,255
  197: 0,0,0,255
  198: 0,0,0,255
  199: 0,0,0,255
  200: 0,0,0,255
  201: 0,0,0,255
  202: 0,0,0,255
  203: 0,0,0,255
  204: 0,0,0,255
  205: 0,0,0,255
  206: 0,0,0,255
  207: 0,0,0,255
  208: 0,0,0,255
  209: 0,0,0,255
  210: 0,0,0,255
  211: 0,0,0,255
  212: 0,0,0,255
  213: 0,0,0,255
  214: 0,0,0,255
  215: 0,0,0,255
  216: 0,0,0,255
  217: 0,0,0,255
  218: 0,0,0,255
  219: 0,0,0,255
  220: 0,0,0,255
  221: 0,0,0,255
  222: 0,0,0,255
  223: 0,0,0,255
  224: 0,0,0,255
  225: 0,0,0,255
  226: 0,0,0,255
  227: 0,0,0,255
  228: 0,0,0,255
  229: 0,0,0,255
  230: 0,0,0,255
  231: 0,0,0,255
  232: 0,0,0,255
  233: 0,0,0,255
  234: 0,0,0,255
  235: 0,0,0,255
  236: 0,0,0,255
  237: 0,0,0,255
  238: 0,0,0,255
  239: 0,0,0,255
  240: 0,0,0,255
  241: 0,0,0,255
  242: 0,0,0,255
  243: 0,0,0,255
  244: 0,0,0,255
  245: 0,0,0,255
  246: 0,0,0,255
  247: 0,0,0,255
  248: 0,0,0,255
  249: 0,0,0,255
  250: 0,0,0,255
  251: 0,0,0,255
  252: 0,0,0,255
  253: 0,0,0,255
  254: 0,0,0,255
  255: 0,0,0,255
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

(In the first band, only values `0` (for white) and `1`(for black) are actually used.)

Seeing that the palette already maps to 4-component colors (so presumably to RGB**A** values), **is this combination of TIFF bands an allowed and valid one?**

I'm asking because QGIS (both 2.18 and 3) interprets the image blatantly differently than I intended

[image: QGIS screenshot in "Multiband color" mode: The raster appears bright green]

unless explicitly told to display it in "Paletted" mode rather than the "Multiband color" mode it automatically selects when adding the TIFF as raster layer

[image: QGIS screenshot in "Paletted" mode: the raster appears black-and-white]

and further processing the TIFF with GDAL command line tools can lead to unusable results, while other programs (e.g. GIMP) displays it as I intended (first band black-and-white with transparency/opacity controlled by the second band)

[image: GIMP screenshot: the raster appears black-and-white]

---

<sup>1</sup>In the example image, the Alpha band is set to opaque everywhere. In my real data, I use it to "cut" the image to the area of a Swiss canton.

Comment: Did you already ask if there is a bug in QGIS or not from QGIS-users mailing list?

Comment: Not yet, but I will.

Comment: Done: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2018-April/042197.html